# extract appid from decoded jwttoken

Tags: powershell, jwt

I have below YAML. where I am using PowerShell script to extract app from Jw token after decoding it. I am not able to get exact app id ( guid )   from the decoded object.  It is coming as  ***

Could someone suggest me how to extract appid from jwt token.

```
parameters:
    - name: jwttoken
      default: ''
     steps:

powershell: |

    $encodedToken = '${{ parameters.jwttoken }}'
    Write-Host $encodedToken
    $tokenParts = $encodedToken -split '\.'
    $tokenPayload = $tokenParts[1]
    #Fix padding as needed, keep adding "=" until string length modulus 4 reaches 0
    while ($tokenPayload.Length % 4) { Write-Verbose "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or       
    string, adding ="; $tokenPayload += "=" }
    $decodedPayload = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($tokenPayload))
    $tokenObject = $decodedPayload | ConvertFrom-Json
     $appId = $tokenObject.appid
     Write-Host $appId
```

Comment: Can you share a sample JWT with a payload containing an `appid` property?